How to turn C Code into Assembly Code that a dissasembler would produce, using GCC?
I want to learn Assembly so I can reverse engineer disassembled Programs eventualy. I figured it would be best to learn C with Assembly side by side.
I know now that there are different stages involved into making C code into an executable.
My Question now is into what Stage I should compile the C Code so I have Assembly code which I would expect in a Dissasembler?
The following is code before the linker processed the file into an executable which was produced with the following command: gcc examplecode.c -s
Is this the right thing or would a disasembler give me code of the actual executable file?
examplecode.c
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    char testVar = '-';
    printf ("%x", testVar);
    
}

- examplecode.s
    .file   "main.c"
    .text
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
.LC0:
    .ascii "%x\0"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $48, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 48
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    movb    $45, -1(%rbp)
    movsbl  -1(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edx
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rcx
    call    printf
    nop
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .ident  "GCC: (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 13.1.0"
    .def    printf; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef


The immediate answer to the question in your title is that you compile your C source into an executable and then put that through a disassembler. Beyond that, it's a bit unclear to me what you're asking.

You can also tell GCC to output assembler code directly.  It might not be exactly the same as a disassembler would produce from the executable.  C executables have very little metadata in them; the GCC assembler code would almost certainly be easier to read.  You can also compare the assembler outputs side-by-side.

A disassembler would give you pretty much the same code except the nice readable names of labels, directives and pseudo-instructions, unless you binary has debug information and the disassembler is able to use it.

i tried dissasembling this code in ghidra and it gave me nothing readable. Guess im doing something wrong then

What "this code" ? You can disassemble binaries, not code. "Nothing readable" is relative too.

I suggest you use the Godbolt online compiler. It color-codes the assembly output so you can see how it corresponds to the original C code. https://godbolt.org/

Related: How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output? for tips on looking at compiler asm output, including using Godbolt.  And see Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk “What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”

I would suggest always using optiomizations if you want to understand real programs

@Barmar -Peter Cordes, thanks guys this was what I was looking for. I was wondering why gcc has diferent outputs on my PC compared to Godbolt.

Besides the "noise" filtering and Godbolt defaulting to Intel syntax, MinGW targets the Windows calling convention.  Godbolt runs on Linux. (Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?)

Note: You can run your own instance of godbolt too if you don't want to share your mistakes^Wsecret source with the world. It really is the best way to compare C/C++ source with generated assembly I know of.
